# Composing Projections on a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $P,Q$ be projections on a Hilbert space such that $PQ$ is a projection.

I have been able to prove that $PQ=QP$.

I want to show that $ker(PQ)$ is contained in $ker(P)+ker(Q)$.

If there's a mathematician who would lend a hand, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you mean a projection $P^{2}=P$ or an orthogonal projection $P^{2}=P=P^{\star}$?

Comment: Orthogonal projection.

Comment: @T.A.E. Doesn't matter, $P^2 = P$ is all that's needed for this.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Can you show that $PQ=QP$ from knowing that $P$, $Q$, $PQ$ are projections, but not necessarily orthogonal projections?

Comment: @T.A.E. I doubt it (I see no obvious way). But the OP had already proved $PQ = QP$, and given two commuting projections $\ker (PQ) \subset \ker P + \ker Q$ follows, for that part you don't need self-adjointness. That was what I meant with "this".

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: A friend just pointed this out to me about general projections, and I thought you would be amused. If $P$ and $Q$ and projections onto the same subspace, then $P$ is the identity on the range of $Q$ and $Q$ is the identity on the range of $P$--so $PQ=Q$ and $QP=Q$, which means $PQ=QP$ iff $P=Q$. That makes for good counter-examples.

Comment: Nice, @T.A.E. Easier counterexample than I expected. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For a projection $P$, we have

$$\ker P = \operatorname{im} (I - P).$$

Comment: Is it true that $(I-PQ)=(I-P)+(I-Q)$?

Comment: No, but $I-PQ = I-P+P-PQ$.

Comment: The third "$=$" ought to be a "$\subset$", you generally don't have $\operatorname{im} (f+g) = \operatorname{im} f + \operatorname{im} g$, only the inclusion. For the last part, you need to use $PQ = QP$.

Comment: ker$(PQ)=$ im$(I-PQ)=$ im$(I-P+P(I-Q)) \subset $ im$(I-P)+$ im$(P(I-Q))=$ im$(I-P)+$ im$(P) \cap $ im$(I-Q)=$ ker$(P)+$ im$(P) \cap $ ker$(Q)$

Comment: I'm trying to prove using $PQ=QP$ either that im$(P) \subset$ ker$(Q)$ or that im$(P) \supset$ ker$(Q)$.

Comment: Look at $\operatorname{im} (P(I-Q))$. If you use the commuting there, what do you get?

Comment: Do I want to show that im$(P(I-Q))=$ im$(I-Q)$?

Comment: Not "$=$", but "$\subset$".

Comment: Right.  The map $(I-Q)P$ is the restriction of the map $(I-Q)$ to im$(P)$, so we have the inclusion.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me! @Daniel Fischer